# Is there an easier way to link back to the index.html file?

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor, href

I am trying to link back to my `index.html` from a sub folder inside my portfolio, right now I have a method that "works", but it feels like the long route. Here is what the "link" looks like in Notepad++ `<a class="navlist" href="/College/Tech%20Classes/HTML%20and%20JavaScript/Midterm%20Project/index.html">Home</a>`.

I was curious if there is a different/easier way to link back to my `index.html`?

Edit: I guess I should mention that I am doing this within this said folder/html file `L:\College\Tech Classes\HTML and JavaScript\Midterm Project\HTMLJava\htmljava.html`.

Comment: Where is the subfolder located?

Comment: L:\College\Tech Classes\HTML and JavaScript\Midterm Project\HTMLJava\htmljava.html

I apologize for not initially adding that into my question at first. @Mureinik

Comment: If you visit /College/Tech%20Classes/HTML%20and%20JavaScript/Midterm%20Project does it automatically resolve to using the index.html file?

Comment: with the way i have it written, it does work. I just felt that it was the long way @kinakuta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a relative link where `..` means going up one folder. E.g.:

```
<a class="navlist" href="../index.html">Home</a>
```

Comment: that did help. Thanks. I wanted to think that was the solution, but I wasn't sure.

If I may ask hypothetically, would that work if I was two subfolder's in because I have a folder within the "HTML and Javascript" for the games I want to link to that page. If not, how would I get that to work?

Comment: @StevenLedoux Not sure I understood the question correctly, but if I did, you can go more than one folder "upwards". E.g. - `../../someFolder/someFile.html`.

Comment: I apologize, I am horrible with words. but I will give what you suggested a test. essentially I have a game in a folder that is located within the "HTML and Javascript" folder (example folder name: "10riddles") with the file riddles.html

Comment: @StevenLedoux So from the page you referenced in the OP you could link to it as `../../10riddles/riddles.html`.

Comment: Again, thank you for your help. I will get to work on this right away.